# Handling errors in threaded tasks like file downloading

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, error-handling

Say I have an application that uses thread to download files through HTTP or FTP. I can imagine a few things going wrong in the background that would require some error handling:

- The distant host becomes unavailable.
- The download speed is too slow.
- Some data is corrupt (if checks in place).
- No data is being sent.
- Content doesn't correspond with expected file type.
- Reported size and data don't correspond.
- ...

How could these be handled in such a way as to relay an error back to the main application ? Or abort if unrecoverable ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a pretty general question with a number of possible solutions.  It depends highly on what information the thread is currently reporting back to the main application.  If, for example, it is returning some remote file-contents in a `String` then `null` could indicate some sort of problem with the data.  If you want more specific information then you will need to maybe create some sort of `JobStatus` class that encapsulates some of the error conditions you mention.  Maybe the class also includes the remote file contents or the actual work payload.

In terms of passing back the information.  The `Runnable` class could have some sort of `getStatus()` method if you are not using a `Callable<...>` and [`ExecutorService` thread-pools](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html#threadpools).  You could also pass a `WorkRequest` class into your `Thread` that it fills out for the job at hand which could include information about any errors encountered.

Typically I tend to rely on logging to show the actual source and details of the problem and rely on exceptions thrown by `Future.get()` to relay back that my processing thread had some sort of problem.  But again, it is hard to determine what makes sense in your environment without a lot more context.

Comment: If a context is needed, think of an application that fetches RSS feeds or an FTP client. Both are of interest to me. A `JobStatus` sounds like a good idea. About `getStatus()`, the idea is to poll the task every now and then ? I have been thinking of a callback pattern but maybe there are downsides. As for using `Future`, I don't really understand what this class represents but, unless mistaken, it is most probably used in `SwingWorker` which I am more familiar with.

Comment: `Future` is used in the excellent `ExecutorService` classes. See here:  http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html#threadpools

Comment: Thank you. I just happened to be looking at the same site :p

Comment: `ExecutorService` thread-pools work best when you have a number of small tasks to do.  You could submit RSS URLs to a thread-pool to be processed.  For each RSS feed, you could submit a `Callable` which passes back your `JobStatus` information.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at java.util.concurrent specifically Executors, and Executor service.  An Executor is a thread pool that you submit tasks to and you get Futures.  There are many ways to use Executors and they are very powerful.

It is good to understand how threads work, but in practice I have found it extremely rare for me to ever actually create a thread myself.  Let the thread pools handle this, they use all the correct Blocking Queues and if threads die unexpectedly the pool will make a new thread(s) to replace it.  All you have to handle is passing a single Runnable, Callable, or lists of either of these and handling the Futures.

Since Callables throw Exception you can handle them in the main class when you get the Future from the Executor.